# MVC Cannot locate font files after publishing to IIS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Franework ASP.Net MVC 4**

This is another instance of "it worked until I published".

Running my MVC 4 site from Visual studio, everything works great. However, when I publish - font awesome breaks. Looking at the Chrome console, I am seeing this:

```
GET http://localhost:4321/Content/themes/crisp/font/zocial.woff?94486700 404 (Not Found)
```

Which is referenced in my CSS like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'zocial';
  src: url('/Content/themes/crisp/font/zocial.eot?94486700');
  src: url('/Content/themes/crisp/font/zocial.woff?94486700') format('woff'),
       url('/Content/themes/crisp/font/social.ttf?94486700') format('truetype'),
       url('/Content/themes/crisp/font/zocial.svg?94486700#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And I have checked - the files are in the site directory:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Didn't know where else to ask this but, how do you put screenshots in a post?

Comment: @CSharper In the toolbar at the top of your question there is a button that looks like a Polaroid that allows you to upload an image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a feeling you need to add the MIME types to the web.config of your application (or globally in the IIS manager).

Try adding:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

to your web.config.

If you run into duplicate key issues that means your IIS instance has some of these extensions already. To allow you to control the MIME type for all the extensions, add:

```
<remove fileExtension=".woff" />
<remove fileExtension=".eot" />
<remove fileExtension=".svg" />
<remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
```

before the `<mimeMap>` elements.

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue now. but the thing is if i use `<staticContent>` no css,js files are loading, if i remove it, everything is working perfect except the font. Please help

Comment: @RajSan I think more information is needed to help you. I would ask a new question with referencing this question and the information in your situation. That will allow the entire community to read and answer your issue as well.